# Fade out two lines of text simoultanously

Tags: jquery, fadeout

I'm new to jQuery and I'm working on a text fader. This is the structure:

HTML:

```
            <section id="header-fader">
    <h2 id="h2-1" class="fader-h2 fader-all">Title 1</h2>
    <p id="p-1" class="fader-p fader-all">text 1</p>    

    <h2 id="h2-2" class="fader-h2 fader-all">title 2</h2>
    <p id="p-2" class="fader-p fader-all">text 2</p>    

    (more h2 and p goes here)

    </section>
```

jQUery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#h2-1').delay(1000).fadeIn(2000);
$('#p-1').delay(3000).fadeIn(2000);
$('fader-all').delay(5000).fadeOut(2000);


$('#h2-2').delay(8000).fadeIn(2000);
$('#p-2').delay(10000).fadeIn(2000);
$('.fader-all').delay(1000).fadeOut(2000);

(more goes here)

});
```

The idea is for h2 and p to fadeIn one after another, and then for both of them to fadeOut at the same time.

So far I've achieved half -  fades in, then

fades in, but then they fade out one after another instead of fading out simultaneously. It looks ugly, as when h2 fades out, it makes the space for p, which jumps up - not something I want to see on my website.

What am I doing wrong? I'm stuck with this for days and I've been postponing it, focusing on other aspects of the page, but now's the time it should really start working.

Help appreciated!

Comment: firstly, you should use position absolute so they don't jump /move around at all from where they should be..

Comment: You're right, I was hesitating as I wasn't sure if it won't affect the responsiveness, but I think it won't. 

Anyway, the jumping is a secondary issue, the most important for me is to fade them out at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the delays and fade-outs at the same time, like this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/V4bmt/11/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#h2-1').delay(1000).fadeIn(2000).delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);
    $('#p-1').delay(3000).fadeIn(2000).fadeOut(2000);


    $('#h2-2').delay(8000).fadeIn(2000).delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);
    $('#p-2').delay(10000).fadeIn(2000).fadeOut(2000);

});
```

Also, if you want them to fade in from the start, they should be hidden from the start. I've added `style="display:none;"` to all elements in the fiddle, but you could handle it with jQuery as well.

Answer (score 2):

firstly, you should use position absolute so they don't jump /move around at all from where they should be.

Then the reason it's not working on both fading out at the same time is because you use the individual id to fade them in, so stick with that on fading them out. I corrected this below, and set the timings so they'll fade out at the same time now.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#h2-1').delay(1000).fadeIn(2000);
$('#p-1').delay(3000).fadeIn(2000);
$('#h2-1').delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);
$('#p-1').fadeOut(2000);

$('#h2-2').delay(8000).fadeIn(2000);
$('#p-2').delay(10000).fadeIn(2000);
$('#h2-2').delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);
$('#p-2').fadeOut(2000);

});
```

Comment: Sorry for answering later, I first checked out the fiddles below, but now I put your code in one and it works perfect as well. Thnx!

Comment: Hi, I know what you mean with voting - I tried to vote up for all the answers here, but I got a message that I don't have enough reputation to vote (I think 15 is minimal). I wanted to write about it yesterday, but guess what - I didn't have enough reputation to answer so fast ;) that's why I'm writing now.

If it comes to accepting the answer, I don't really see any option to do it here - any idea when will it show up?

So far all I can do is verbally express my gratitude, but once my reputation grows, you can be sure that I'll reward the helpful folks :)

Comment: Ok, thnx for the explanation, it worked with the checkmark! I simply haven't paid attention to the button, guess I perceived it as decoration. My reputation has risen to 15 in the meantime, so voting up is done here as well :)

Answer (score 1):

I've made a jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KMmQ9/).

The code:

```
var hDelay = 1000,
    pDelay = 3000,
    fadeOutDelay = 6000;

$('#h2-1').delay(hDelay).fadeIn(2000);
$('#p-1').delay(pDelay).fadeIn(2000);

$('#h2-1').delay(fadeOutDelay - hDelay).fadeOut(2000);
$('#p-1').delay(fadeOutDelay - pDelay).fadeOut(2000);
```

Comment: This works as well :) Thnx a lot, I can finally move forward thanks to you guys!